# Выборка данных из БД до определенного значения в поле

Tags: mysql, база-данных, веб-программирование

[image]

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста с такого рода вопросом.
Имеется БД MySQL, в таблице есть определенные данные. Как грамотно сформировать запрос, чтобы из таблицы вытащить все записи с category_id = 1, но ограниченные до момента, когда в поле after записано 'end', т.е. далее этого значения - выборка не производится. Записи с одинаковым category_id идут по порядку. (На картинке из таблицы нужно получить все, что выделено зеленым). 
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from table where category_id = 1 and
id <= (select min(id) from table where category_id = 1 and after = 'end')
```

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо большое!